# unicode converter buffer over flow

Tags: connection, odbc, vertica

When I am trying establish a ODBC connection in cognos connect to vertica database, I am getting “Unicode converter buffer over flow”.  Please guide me inthis issue.

Thanks,
Indu

Answer (score 0):

Try adding DriverUnicodeType=1 into odbc.ini for your vertica dsn entry.
This will cause the driver to use utf-16 instead of utf-8 it uses by default.

A sample ODBC setup for Datastage: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21587289

Comment: I have used DriverUnicodeType=1 in my odbc.ini, still I am getting "unicode converter buffer overflow" issue.